# How to sort rows from a column that refer to multiple rows from the following columns as merging is a no no...?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I have a retreat paying participants list.
Each participant name from first column refers to multiple rows in following columns that include info stacked horizontally like, date/form/payment value.

This means the first column has empty spaces between the participant names.

Can I sort A-Z the sheet by the names preserving the reference to the multiple rows in the following columns?[screenshot of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuzba.png)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to fill the rest like:

[image]

and then sort it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT({IF(B2:B="",, 
 VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1)), B2:B}))
```

[image]